# Receive Google Autocomplete Results in Local Language

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google JavaScript API V3 allows to change the language in either English, German or French, but when I search for "Cologne" in English API it should return me "Köln", same as if I search for "Frankfurt" in French, it shall return me "Frankfurt" and not "Francfort". People might search all across Europe and I want to get the specific results in each of the resulted cities' local language. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

When using Autocomplete service via the JavaScript API,the API detects the browser's setting for the end user and sets the language appropriately. Please see our doc for reference:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization

That being said, if you don't include the language parameter when calling the JS API, the language will default to the setting in the end users' browser. This would most likely be the local language for that user.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Stephen, this does not help unfortunately. I want to have the result in the language of the place. Meaning, if I search for Beijing, and my browser is German, I want to receive the result of 北京. Any idea?

Comment: Hello, sorry for my misunderstanding! Currently, there is no set way to change the language dynamically based on the query string input by the user.

Comment: Due to the fact that the language must be set when calling the JS API, there isn't really a good workaround for this. You would need to take the user input and find out what the local language is for the city the user inputs. After that you would need to modify your JS API call in the script tag and set it to the local language determined previously. After that you would need to call the JS API again with the language set. I'd recommend filing a feature request for this against the [JS API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=787814)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, at least partially.

Let me start by pointing out the premises:

- The Maps APIs and Google Maps will be consistent in the following.
- Names of political entities are shown in the user's preferred language.
- Street-level addresses are shown in the local language, with a script friendly to the based on its preferred language.

With these in mind, you can do the following:

1. Once users selects a city (`place_changed` event is fired), take the
   `types` and `location` latlng of the city.
2. Do a reverse geocode of the location latlng of the city.
3. Search for results with `location_type` other than `"APPROXIMATE"`.
4. In those results, search for the `address_component` with the same `types` as the city. That will be the name of the city, in the local language.

Examples: get "Köln" for a French user:

1. User types "Cologne" and selects "Cologne, Allemagne".
2. City has latlng 50.937531,6.960279 and `types: ["locality", "political"]`.
3. Reverse geocoding of 50.937531,6.960279 returns 2 results with `location_type` other than `"APPROXIMATE"`.
4. From the first result, 4th `address_component` has `types: ["locality", "political"]`. It's name is "Köln".

Note that names are *always* in a script friendly to the user, so you get "Beijing" for a German user (instead of "北京") or "Tōkyō-to" instead of "東京都".